# C library linking in linux

Tags: c, xls

I have been working on a C code for which I needed some functions of libxls.h header files. I have already downloaded the corresponding files  and followed the installation instruction. The files also contained a test C code (test.c) which I tried compiling. The results were as follow:

1. Command to compile the test.c file-
   gcc test.c -lm

Results:

```
[root@XXXXXXX95549 test]# gcc test.c -lm
test.c:28:24: error: libxls/xls.h: No such file or directory
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:33: error: ‘xlsWorkBook’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:33: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:33: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:33: error: ‘pWB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:34: error: ‘xlsWorkSheet’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:34: error: ‘pWS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:39: error: ‘WORD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t’
test.c:53: error: ‘t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:58: error: ‘tt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:60: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:64: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:66: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:67: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:68: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:70: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:70: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
test.c:71: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

2. To solve this problem, I copied the library files at the '/user/include' location

After which the results for same compilation commands were:

```
[root@XXXXXX95549 test]# gcc test.c -lm
/tmp/cc8DJETV.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `xls_open'
test.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `xls_getWorkSheet'
test.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `xls_parseWorkSheet'
test.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `xls_getCSS'
test.c:(.text+0x49c): undefined reference to `xls_showBookInfo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please, explain how can I rectify this problem.

The code test.c is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <libxls/xls.h>

int main()
{

    xlsWorkBook* pWB;
    xlsWorkSheet* pWS;
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    struct st_row_data* row;
    WORD t,tt;
    pWB=xls_open("files/test2.xls", "ASCII"); // "KOI8-R"

    if (pWB!=NULL)
    {
        f=fopen ("test.htm", "w");
        for (i=0;i<pWB->sheets.count;i++)
            printf("Sheet N%i (%s) pos %i\n",i,pWB->sheets.sheet[i].name,pWB->sheets.sheet[i].filepos);

        pWS=xls_getWorkSheet(pWB,0);
        xls_parseWorkSheet(pWS);
        fprintf(f,"<style type=\"text/css\">\n%s</style>\n",xls_getCSS(pWB));
        fprintf(f,"<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>");

        for (t=0;t<=pWS->rows.lastrow;t++)
        {
            row=&pWS->rows.row[t];
            //      xls_showROW(row->row);
            fprintf(f,"<tr>");
            for (tt=0;tt<=pWS->rows.lastcol;tt++)
            {
                if (!row->cells.cell[tt].ishiden)
                {
                    fprintf(f,"<td");
                    if (row->cells.cell[tt].colspan)
                        fprintf(f," colspan=%i",row->cells.cell[tt].colspan);
                    //              if (t==0) fprintf(f," width=%i",row->cells.cell[tt].width/35);
                    if (row->cells.cell[tt].rowspan)
                        fprintf(f," rowspan=%i",row->cells.cell[tt].rowspan);
                    fprintf(f," class=xf%i",row->cells.cell[tt].xf);
                    fprintf(f,">");
                    if (row->cells.cell[tt].str!=NULL && row->cells.cell[tt].str[0]!='\0')
                        fprintf(f,"%s",row->cells.cell[tt].str);
                    else
                        fprintf(f,"%s","&nbsp;");
                    fprintf(f,"</td>");
                }
            }
            fprintf(f,"</tr>\n");
        }
        fprintf(f,"</table>");
        printf("Count of rows: %i\n",pWS->rows.lastrow);
        printf("Max col: %i\n",pWS->rows.lastcol);
        printf("Count of sheets: %i\n",pWB->sheets.count);

        fclose(f);
        xls_showBookInfo(pWB);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You've got your answer in your title. You need to _link_ to the library. `-lxls`.

Comment: ... and manually copying arbitrary (include-) files to system directories is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you explain me what I am missing.. Or the procedure for linking libraries.. I am new to this..
after using -lxls with gcc, it gives following error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxls

Comment: You have to provide path to your include files using `-I` option and path to missing library using `-L` option. For example `gcc test.c -Lyour_path_to_lib -lxls -lm -o test`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to this question on the following location:

http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2018568/

Those who might be facing the problem with libxls library can refer the above mentioned website.

cheers